# Feret's Diameter c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, feret-value

I have been working with OpenCv for months and I was wondering if someone can help me with one of the algorithms.

I want to calculate the `Feret's diameter (8, 16,32 or 64)` with c++ and in OpenCv library, I couldn't find any function.

Can any one suggest any solution or algorithm?

Thanks

Comment: Please give this a try and post some code before asking for help.

Comment: Only a few centimetres, unless it's been hugely overfed.

Comment: I could already calculate the Minimum and Maximum Feret's diameter by using the rotating bounding box.

Comment: Note that the rotating bounding box will give you only the smallest Feret diameter, not the longest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rotation of the bounding box, but it is the brute force solution. Here is a [simpler solution using the convex hull](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/408).

I think that this [link is a faster algorithm using the Freeman chain code](http://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/339#more-339).

Comment: Im working on the rotating bounding box, it works OK but Im sure its not the easiest solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But they are working in Matlab not c++. In matlab there is a function called imferetdiameter that calculates the Feret's diameter

Comment: These algorithms are given to be much faster, and it would make a big difference considering how slow the rotating bounding box algorithm is. I haven't implemented them.

Comment: Here is my C++ implementation of the Feret diameters from the convex hull: https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib/blob/43817114fe1dd0dc11b2f8ab7fe5c154b166542e/src/measurement/measure_polygon.cpp#L115